# Unity 2d space between sprites

Tags: unity-game-engine

The game I'm developing has side scrolling background.I have many background sprites
and when the first background image exit from the bounds of screen, I add another background.
when I add new backgrounds I simply check the width of background sprite and,instantiate(while moving) after current background but it shows tiny line between background images.

```
renderer = mapObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
mapWidth = renderer.bounds.size.x;

//instantiate new map to new position
addMap(newMap,new Vector3(mapWidth,0f,0f));
```

Is this problem occur because I instantiate the new sprite while moving the 
current one? or any ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: Does the line vanish if you pause the scrolling?  Perhaps it is a VSYNC-Off tearing issue?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.line doesn't vanish even pause the scrolling.so I think it's a problem with the position the object instantiated

Comment: and I tried to adjust the space adding extra values(which I don't want to do manually) to mapWidth then sometimes the line appears while scrolling.may be different with positioning and looks like VSync issue in this case.

Comment: OK.  Try finding a solution with the scrolling disabled for now.  If you can still see it then I wouldn't think it's to do with Vsync tearing

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your sprite's scale is not (1, 1, 1)

you can try this

```
GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.x
```

I did this work with the code before with a Editor to unit the sprites.

Here is my code

```
public void SortMaps() {
    float sceenHeight = Camera.main.orthographicSize * 2;
    float aspectRatio = 760f / 660f;
    float sceenWidth = sceenHeight * aspectRatio;
    float proportion = sceenWidth / mapBgs.transform.GetChild (0).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.bounds.size.x;
    //In my method the sprite's width should equal to the sceen's width, so the first sprite's position should be -(sceenHeight / 2 - sceenWidth / 2)
    float initY = -(sceenHeight / 2 - sceenWidth / 2);

    //First sprite
    mapBgs.transform.GetChild (0).name = "MapBg01";
    mapBgs.transform.GetChild (0).transform.position = new Vector3 (0, initY, 0);
    mapBgs.transform.GetChild (0).transform.localScale = new Vector3(proportion, proportion, 0);
    for (int i = 1; i < mapBgs.transform.childCount; i++)
    {
        mapBgs.transform.GetChild(i).name = "MapBg" + (i + 1).ToString ().PadLeft (2, '0');
        //change the scale to make the sprite adapt to the sceen
        mapBgs.transform.GetChild(i).transform.localScale = new Vector3(proportion, proportion, 0);
        //Next sprite's position 
        float y = mapBgs.transform.GetChild(i - 1).transform.position.y +
            mapBgs.transform.GetChild(i - 1).gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.y / 2 +
                mapBgs.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.y / 2;
        mapBgs.transform.GetChild(i).transform.position = new Vector3 (0, y, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.as you said scale of the game object was not  (1, 1, 1).it was  (1.1, 1.1, 1.1) but I tried with default scale still line appears.and I used GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.x too but not work.did you add maps inside Update or fixedUpdate?

Comment: I added maps in Editor, before the game running. Did you use SetParent or other function to change the gameobject's parent? If you did, look at the gameobject's localScale after setParent, it may changed. I advice you to print out the GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.x and position. You can Debug in a IEnumerator instead of Update.

Comment: problem is I'm adding maps in FixedUpdate function.should I avoid  Fixedupdate? I have 3-4 textures in one map object.in that it has colliders. if I add all maps before run the game the scene takes time to load and will have memory issues. I didn't use setParent.